# .net WCF, change namespace prefixes in WSDL file

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, xml-namespaces

I have Wcf service and .net generated wsdl file for me.
I must follow certain standard and I need to change namespace prefixes used in wsdl.

Example:

```
<wsdl:definitions .... xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
```

has to be changed to

```
<wsdl:definitions .... xmlns:soapbind="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
```

or

```
xmlns:tns="http://xxx"
```

has to be changed to

```
xmlns:bipro="http://xxx"
```

I know that it doesn't change any functionality but we need to get certification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is here

http://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Custom-wsdl-from-WCF.aspx

you can write own wsdl and change stuff in there